# Error Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 when disable PROGUARD

Tags: android

I have a project that build fine and work fine when the PROGUARD is enabled.

If I disable the proguard in the project.properties and try to export the apk, then it fail with error "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

In the Console and error there is no reference to the error.

I know that usually this error come out when the proguard configuration is wrong, but in my case it is contrary.

What can I check?

Comment: Probably your build script

Comment: I export from Eclipse, I don't use ANT and then there is no build script.

Comment: Aha, and who calls Proguard? Eclipse?

Comment: Please look my question, I meant without PROGUARD.

Comment: Yes but you told, that it runs fine with Proguard, how do you build it with Proguard without a build skript?